# Auto index and auto deletion of index on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-indices

We have the following requirement: every month a new index (collection) has to be created: *company_details-* in ES cluster.
We need to delete the older indices which are greater than 2 months.

*Example:*

```
company_details-2019-12 (delete this index)
company_details-2020-01 (retain this index)
company_details-2020-02 (retain this index)
```

We could create an alias *company_details* and point it to the current month index (so that we could do indexing/querying). This also has to be updated every month automatically.

How can we setup ES so that this would be done automatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a recent version of Elasticsearch, Index Lifecycle Management (ILM) (see Elasticsearch Reference: [Manage the index lifecycle](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html)) can be used to automate all the tasks you described:

- rolling over indices
- adjusting links
- optimize indices according to the life-cycle until they eventually get deleted

Comment: @Somebody if you are using an old version curator can help you